# Get Class name without package from StackTraceElement

Tags: java

I have this `ste.getClassName()` which return a `String` like this `pack.age.Foo`.

`ste` is `StackTraceElement`.

How I could get only `Foo`? Or the only way is to do a method which extract `Foo` from that string?

Comment: Yes, according to the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) it is the only way.

Comment: How about `Class.forName(ste.getClassName()).getSimpleName()`?

Comment: You can use Class.getSimpleName()

Comment: What about `getSimpleName()`?

Comment: The problem with creating a Class instance from the name is, that the class may not be available or accessible at the moment.

Comment: @OndřejXichtSvětlík what do you mean available or accessible?

Comment: @KunLun It can be a private internal class, module-private (not exported from a module) or loaded by a different ClassLoader. And probably more, this is just what I could come up with off the top of my head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a built in method for that. You could break up the string like @Naya and @Daniel Perez suggested, or let `Class` to the heavy lifting for you:

```
String simpleName = Class.forName(ste.getClassName()).getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String fullClassName = stackTraceElement.getClassName();
String simpleClassName = fullClassName.substring(fullClassName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Comment: That is the method I was thinking, but I don't like very much (i don't know why :P) and I thought there is a predefined method for that. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] parts = ste.getClassName.split(".");
```

parts[2] will be the Foo value.
.split allows you to choose a value for which the string will be divided into an array depending on the position of the divider.

Comment: That is the method I was thinking, but I don't like very much (i don't know why :P) and I thought there is a predefined method for that. But thanks!